# How can I change the values in a dataframe column based off the index of a list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

lets say I have a data frame:

```
x     y     
1     3
2     0
4     1
7     2
```

and I have a list:

```
[1,2,7,5]
```

can I change the values of the Y column based on the value of the index of the list?

for instance, for value 2 of the y column its 0. is it anyway to take that 0 and look at the 0th index value of the list and changes it to that value so the 4 would become 1 in the y column?

and for the rest of the values?

so it would be:

```
x     y     
1     5
2     1
4     2
7     7
```

thanks guys

EDIT: FIXED INDEXING (started from 1 instead of 0)

Comment: fwiw python is 0 index based so technically it wouldn't be looking at the index but the index + 1

Comment: that was a mistake. I meant to start from 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do with

```
df.y=np.array(l)[df.y-1]# here i subtract 1 since the index from pandas or numpy is from 0 by default 
df
Out[52]: 
   x  y
0  1  7
1  2  5
2  4  1
3  7  2
```

Comment: I made a mistake I meant to start from 0. so do I just omit that part?

Comment: @BVOM  if that is the case , yes

Comment: I don't know if I did something wrong but the values don't match those of the list

Comment: @BVOM is the above sample match what you need ? if so, you need subtract one

Comment: My list consists of 22 values but the value of y its grabbing doesn't match the value of the index position of the list

Comment: [1, 7, 2, 4, 0, 3, 16, 6, 8, 9, 17, 12, 10, 19, 11, 15, 20, 10, 21, 5, 13, 14] = my list

Comment: but for instance when y is 12, it gives me 20

Comment: @BVOM then maybe change your question ?

Comment: your answer is what I'm looking for but its not working for me

Comment: I'm new around here still so just change the title is what you mean?

Comment: no idk why. for instance when y is 0 based on the list, I should get 1 but instead I get   12

Comment: @BVOM remove subtract 1 `np.array(l)[df.y]
`